# "Error: conflicting requests" in centos 8 package installation

Tags: centos, gdal, yum, centos8

I am trying to install the `gdal` on my centos 8. I tried with following command

```sh
sudo yum install gdal
```

And it through me following error,

```sh
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:58 ago on Sun 10 Jan 2021 10:52:18 PM EST.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libdap.so.25()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libdapclient.so.6()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libdapserver.so.7()(64bit) needed by gdal-libs-3.0.4-5.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Please, anyone, suggest to me, how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the powertools repository to solve this issue,

```sh
sudo yum install dnf-plugins-core
sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Now you can install the gdal by following code,

```sh
sudo yum install gdal-devel
```